# Copy and Paste Style within Excel file

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, xlconnect

This is a refinement of another question of mine ([Duplicate sheet with format in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52831134/edit)). Is it possible to copy the style of one cell and paste it on top of another. Based on the picture below, I would like to copy the style from B2 black font in bold and paste it onto B3 where it is red and italic. I thought I could extract the style with `getCellStyle`and then paste it onto the other cell using `setCellStyle`, but the returned object from `getCellStyle` is actually not a CellStyle when I check with `is.CellStyle`. 
Can I only define CellStyles manually within R?

Note that I can only use `xlxs`or `XLConnect` and **not** `openxlsx`

[image]

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the format (so `RedItalic` would become black and bold?)

Comment: Yes, i added "and paste it"